# Identify Mac M1 architecture devices from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, apple-m1

Is there any way to identify how many users are getting into my website having an apple M1 Mac/OSX architecture?

Answer (score 2):

Currently no, the user agents still say "Intel Mac"